# cordova-plugin-firebase how to remove crashlytics?

Tags: firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, crashlytics

I have installed [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) in an Ionic Cordova application and since I have added this plugin I notice the following error when I debug my app with Xcode

> [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=..., content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}

I don't want to use Fabric/crashlytics in any case

How could I remove it without affecting the Cordova Firebase plugin?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe seems to be a known issue with the latest version of Cordova Firebase plugin. This plugin uses Google Services dependency 4.1.0, but according to the GitHub issues section, this problem will be fixed in the next release by using version 4.2.0.

While waiting for the plugin update, are you using Cordova iOS 5.0 in your project? In that case, try to compile your app again downgrading Cordova iOS version to 4.5.5. Run:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios --save
```

Then:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.5.5 --save
```

Comment: Thx for the tips, I'll keep that in mind, I'm not super motivated I've to say to downgrade cordova-ios as soon Apple will reject bundle submitted with the legacy build